# Selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm trying to send the ID in an dynamic way here is the code:

```
function formsub(val){
    val2 = "form#" + val.toString() + " :input";
    val3 = "form#formmain :input";
    $(val3).each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

When someone click a submit button in the form this will call `formsub` but the problem I get and error:

```
Uncaught exception: Syntax error , unrecognized expression ''
```

I try to use `val3` and it's working fine but when I use `val2` it give me the error but they are the same value.

```
<form id='formmain' method='post' onsubmit='formsub(this.id)'>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type='textbox' required />
    <span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    <br/>
    <label>Male</label>
    <input type='radio' required />
    <span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    <br/>
    <label>Female</label>
    <input type='radio' required />
    <span style='color:red;'>*</span>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' />
    <br/>
</form>
```

The code above is for the form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are *not* the same. `val2` is `form#formmain: input` but `val3` is `form#formmain :input`. Notice the position of the colon.

Comment: @FelixKling Had you made it an answer instead of a comment, it would have been easier to read.

Comment: @dystroy: Yeah, but I voted to close the question and I don't tend to answer in such a case. I did now though, but suggesting an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by others and by me, the position of the colon is different in both strings and that's why you get the error in one case.

However, you can avoid the whole string concatenation if you work directly with the DOM element.

HTML:

```
<form id='formmain' method='post' onsubmit='formsub(this)'>
```

JS:

```
function formsub(ele){
    $(ele).find(':input').each(function () {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Even better if use jQuery to bind the event handler, e.g.:

```
$('form').on('submit', formsub);
// or $('#formmain').on('submit', formsub);
```

Inside the event handler, `this` will refer to the form element then. Learn more about event handling: http://learn.jquery.com/events/.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
val2 = "form#" + val.toString() + ": input";  // form#formmain: input
```

with this:

```
val2 = "form#" + val.toString() + " :input";  // form#formmain :input
```

Also a suggestion, since **ID** are supposed to be unique, you can just use the ID instead of `form#ID`, like:

```
val2 = "#" + val.toString() + " :input";      // #formmain :input
```

Also, you can modify the js like:

```
function formsub(val) {
    val2 = "#" + val.toString() + " :input";
    val3 = "#formmain :input";
    $(val2).each(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
val2="form#"+val+" :input";
```

Let me know is this helpfull?

Answer (score 2):

As I have analysis the code, I see that there is minor difference between val2 and val3:

Replace your val2 with this:

```
val2="form#"+val.toString()+" :input";
```

As you have forgot the space.

Answer (score 2):

No space between `:` and `input` it should be `:input`

```
function formsub(val){
    val2="form#" + val.toString() + ":input"; // no space between : and input
    val3="form#formmain :input";
    $(val3).each(function(){
        var input = $(this);alert($(this).val());   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("form#" + val.toString() + ":input").each(function(){
 var input = $(this);  
 alert(input.val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry but the ID is passed and not only for the formmain I want it to be dynamic